# Export Highcharts Chart with FontAwesome Icons in Labels

Tags: highcharts, export, font-awesome

I'm trying to get Highcharts to export a chart with FontAwesome icons in plotline labels. I've set up my own export server (as per the instructions at https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server) and this is successfully creating export files, but the FontAwesome icons are not showing.  I've installed the FontAwesome ttf font file on the machine and I've added the relevant code to support use of HTML in the labels and when exporting:

```
label: {
    text: '<strong><i class="fa fa-cup fa-lg"></i><br />Water<br />Station</strong>',
    useHTML: true
}
```

```
exporting: {
    allowHTML: true,
    url: "http://localhost:7801"
}
```

The font icons are correctly showing on the screen, just not when exporting. Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Comment: You need to insert CSS of FontAwesome in order to use it. Go to https://export.highcharts.com/ and place the JS and CSS from the following demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/net5u2h9/ into corresponding fields to see that it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm not sure how to expose the FontAwesome css to the export server though. I already have a link to the FontAwesome css on the web page that is creating the chart and the FontAwesome icons display OK on screen. I'm making the export request by calling chart.exportChart.

Comment: @JohnPiears, Did you find the solution ?